# How to reference a picker that is created in xaml when a label is clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

So I am doing a Xamarin forms multiplatform app. I have a label and an invisible picker. When the label is clicked, I want the picker to become visible. I am not sure how to reference the picker in the code behind file for the event handler.

I created this gesture recognizer for the label:

```
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                 <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="LabelTap1"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

I can't use sender since it obviously would just be the label object. Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give your `Picker` a name, which will result in a variable in your code-behind. Change your picker by adding this attribute:

`<Picker x:Name="MyPicker" />`

Then in your code-behind, you can simply do this:

`MyPicker.IsVisible = true;`

Comment: Lol I literally had done that already and it didn't seem to be working (when I typed the picker's name into the code it was acting as if it didn't exist), and I had researched it and came to the conclusion that you can't reference it that way. I went back to doublecheck before reporting back to you that it doesn't work and of course it works. No idea what changed. Thanks!